# Why jquery submit may not work?

Tags: jquery, post

I have form where before i was using simple post with `<button name="submit" id="register" value="Register">Continue</button>`

than i decided to change that post to jquery ajax post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#register").click(function () {

            if (!$("form").valid())
                return false;

            var isContinue = false;

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Validate",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { recaptcha_challenge_field: $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val(), recaptcha_response_field: $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val() },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    isContinue = data === 'true';
                },
                error: function (xhr, st, err) {
                    alert("Sorry error occured, try again later.");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    alert(isContinue);//i could see that alert
                    if (isContinue) {
                        alert(isContinue); //i could see that alert
                        $("form").submit();
                        alert(isContinue); //i could see that alert
                    }
                    else {

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
<a class="button" id="register">Continue</a
```

So if all validation including capthca passed than when i clicking to submit button and form does not posted on server. I checked request with chrome and opera `network dev tools` and they didn't show that post action, but according with alerts which i placed in javascript the form should be posted.

Then for test i placed another simple submit button and form getting posted so for some reason `$("form").submit();`  don't want to post the form.

May be some one may have any ideas what it could be?

**UPDATE**

I was commenting the `ajax post button` when i tried `simple post button` but the thing is
i was having another `back button` :) which is looking like that:

```
<button name="submit" class="cancel" id="back" value="Back">
```

so the problem is really with `name="submit"`, i just remove that and all working now. 
It would take very long time to figure out that the problem just with `name="submit"`, thanks for help.

Comment: JavaScript is turned off? :) It might sound crazy to you but I think you should make sure the essential aspects of your website also work without javascript. This includes something as basic as a form post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the button you've named `submit` is overriding the `submit` method on the `form` element, so instead of `form.submit` being a function that submits the form, it's now a reference to the `button` element.

The easiest way of fixing this is to rename your `button` element.

It's important to differentiate between `$('form').submit()` and `form.submit()`. `$('form').submit)` is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/submit) that is not affected by the button named submit, however behind the scenes, jQuery calls the `submit` attribute on the *actual* `HTMLForm` element, which **is** affected by the button named `submit`.

There is a [bug about this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414) on http://bugs.jquery.com, however as described above, it's not *actually* a problem with jQuery itself.

You're code has another problem; you shouldn't be using `$('form')` inside your click handler, as this is building a jQuery object to **alllll** forms on your page; so you're checking that **alllll** forms are valid, and submitting ***alll*** forms. Instead, use `$(this).closest('form')`

Comment: it is amazing, tanks from help

Comment: i know about that, that `$('form').submit()` would submit all forms,but i constantly have only one form, but it could be a problem if i would have more that one form on page you right.

Answer (score 0):

That is valid function?
It return false, on submit.

```
    if (!$("form").valid())
        return false;
```